# Spring security context is not updated on AuthenticationManager.authenticate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a custom authentication process for REST API back end.
Some implementation details:

1. I implemented custom `AuthenticationProvider` which authenticates user successfully and returns `Authentication` object.
2. I registered brand new `AuthenticationManager` like this to skip some spring boot auto configuration:

```
    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager() {
        return AuthenticationManager()
    }
```

3. In my `AuthController` I have `/login` endpoint. The logic of this is fairly simple: it converts DTO to custom `Authentication` object and calls `AuthenticationManager.authenticate(my_custom_authentication)`.

Note: I do **not** directly manipulate `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` anywhere in my code.

The problem is that security context is not get updated after successful authentication and when I try to access `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` in spring interceptor post processing method I see it is not my `Authentication` object from custom `AuthenticationProvider` I got after successful authentication.

Here are some questions:

1. Is it ok and common to directly access `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` to edit it? It feels wrong and hacky to do something like this.
2. I thought that `AuthenticationManager` handles security context updates on its own. I mean we call `AuthenticationManager.authenticate(my_custom_authentication)` and it updates context on successful authentication. If it is not the case and we should keep security context up-to-date manually why do we even need to have `AuthenticationManager`?

Can you please point me on my mistakes if any?
Also if there is classical rest api spring based login and security implementation it would be very nice to look at this as it seems there are a lot of things to be done for this to work properly.

**EDIT**
Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/mr-nothing/spring-security-rest-issue) to represent the issue I have.

Comment: Can you please put your customAuthenticationProvider code?

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad Hey, unfortunately I'm unable to post it here as it is private code. I assure you there is nothing special in it. It just returns object with `isAuthenticated()==true` and principle object populated.

Comment: Why do you create a new (empty) authentication manager? Just register your custom `AuthenticationProvider` with the existing `Authenticationmanager`. Then it should work. The `AuthenticationManager` will set the context.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hm, it would be nice if you can share a code snippet of how to do this. I tried tons of solutions but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to skip the auto config of Spring Security add an `@Configuration` class with `@EnableWebSecurity`. Don't register an empty `AuthenticationManager`.

Add a bean for your custom provider and register that with the `AuthenticationManager` through the [`AuthenticationManagerBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html#authenticationProvider-org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider-).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public void WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) { ... // Security config here}

  @Bean
  public CustomAuthenticationProvider customProvider() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customProvider());
  }

}
```

This will configure the `AuthenticationManager` to use your customized `AuthenticationProvider`. If you use a recent version of Spring Security (not sure which version includes this) it is enough to just configure your custom `AuthenticationProvider` which will then be automatically detected by the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. See [the Spring Security Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-authenticationprovider) as well.

The `SecurityContext` is being set by the filter chain (for instance through the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` which delegates authentication itself to the `AuthenticationManager`.

## Update

The crucial part in  your project is that your login endpoint is basically bypassing everything in Spring Security. The main part of Spring Security is implemented in filters, if you want to authenticate in a web application (regardless the mechanism) you will need to add a filter to the chain.

```
public CustomAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  private final ObjectMapper mapper;

  public CustomAuthenticationFilter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/login", "POST"));
    this.mapper=mapper;
  }

  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException,
            ServletException {

      MyPrincipal principal = mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), MyPrincipal.class);
      MyAuthentication authentication = new MyAuthentication(principal);
      setDetails(request, authentication); //assuming you are extending AbstractAuthenticationToken
      return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authentication);

   }

    protected void setDetails(HttpServletRequest request,
            MyAuthentication authRequest) {
        authRequest.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
    }

}
```

In your configuration add this filter to Spring Security and configure the filter accordingly.

```
@Bean
public CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    CustomAuthenticationFilter filter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(mapper);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    return filter;
}

// To prevent registering the filter in the default filter chain!
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationbean customAuthenticationFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterReg = new FilterRegistrationBean(customAuthenticationFilter());
    filterReg.setEnabled(false);
    return filterReg;
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) {

    http.addFilterBefore(customerAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    // other config here
}
```

Now your authentication is part of the Spring Security part.

Comment: Thank you very much for response but it seems that it doesn't work this way. As per [this decussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11136) developer is forced to provide it's own `AuthenticationManager` starting spring boot 2.0.0. I did it as shown in this thread but security context is still not updated after my provider did its job.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? That only relates to when using the auto configuration. This isn't used due to the `@EnableWebSecurity`. Hence the normal Spring Security configuration options apply (as mentioned in the linked Spring Security documentation).

Comment: Yes I did, I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/mr-nothing/spring-security-rest-issue) to represent an issue. It would be nice if you can tell what is wrong with this.

Comment: I clearly stated you shuld have `@EnableWebSecurity` you don't. Also you are bypassing Spring Security for login, so the defaults don't apply. Why do you have your own `LoginController`? You should have a filter as part of the Spring Security chain else things won't work. Create a filter that extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and implement the logic in there.

Comment: Thanks, if I add `@EnableWebSecurity` and remove `authenticationManagerBean` the application do not start because of `AuthenticationManager` absence.

Regarding bypassing Spring Security for login endpoint: yeah, it is intended, as I said before I'm trying to implement REST API so I need public `/login` for authentication purposes.

Comment: Don't bypass Spring Security, instead of a controller (which executes AFTER spring security) make it part of the security chain. As mentioned create a filter that includes the logic you now have in your controller and make it part of the Spring Security chain. The fact that you are bypassing Spring Security is in essence what is wrong, due to that your login doesn't work to register things with Spring Security. Now you could hack all of that into your Controller, but instead use a filter and get all of that out-of-the-box.

Comment: Tbh I don't think I understand. How should I design rest api `/login` then? How should I pass data from request body to authentication filter in this case?

Comment: Use an `Objectmapper` to parse the body (the same as Spring web does internally). You need to do that yourself. The `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` passes the request and response to the `attemptAuthentication` method, you can use that to read the body using the pre-configured `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Ok, I understand the approach. Though it sounds hacky to set up this and have empty `/login` endpoint... Task looked like really easy one but it turns out it is not.

Comment: You don't need the `/login` endpoint, that is being replaced by the filter. Just write a filter that does the same as you are doing in the controller, nothing more nothing less. With the addition that you need to parse the input.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option. `/login` endpoint is one of the client requirements.

Comment: Again you don't need the endpoint. You need something for hte URL this is the filter NOT the `@RestController`  you have now. I've updated my answer, with how to create and register the filter. Not sure if it works as is (as I typed it from the top of my head).

Comment: Thank you very much! With your help I was able to implement the solution in accordance with requirements. Regarding `/login` endpoint: if after successful authentication we proceed with security chain processing spring complains about absence of `/login` endpoint, so we are forced to create it. As a benefit we can move business logic (which is not related to authentication) to controller logic from auth provider. Thanks again, you helped a lot!

Comment: You shouldn't proceed processing if the filter handles the login, just return the status 200 or whatever you like to do. Don't create an additional endpoint just because you need, let the filter do all that. You can do this by adding a `AuthenticationSuccesHandler` which does that.

Comment: Hm, I thought it is enough to override `successfulAuthentication` in `AuthenticationProvider`. I'll definitely try this, thanks again for your help!

Comment: That will work as well, but the default `successfulAuthentication` does a bit more then only call the succes handler (fires an event, remember-me if configured etc.),

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

> **1- Update SecurityContext At entry point (Login)**

- You can update `SecurityContext` in your custom login service. 
  (When the authentication process is done then update `SecurityContext`.

  **I coded this scenario as follows**

  ```
  @Service
  public class CustomLoginService {

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticateManager;

  public void customLogin(HttpServletRequest request, String username, String password) {

      //Custom authentication via your provider
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
      Authentication auth = authenticateManager.authenticate(authReq);

      //Update SecurityContext with authentication information (auth)
      SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
      securityContext.setAuthentication(auth);

      //Set updated securityContext into session of user
      HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
      session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, securityContext);

      }

  }
  ```

> **2- The SecurityContext get updated automatically in the CustomAuthenticationProvider (Edited)**

- When CustomAuthenticationProvider returns `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`,The SecurityContext get updated automatically(e.g save principals of the user)

  **I coded this scenario as follows**

  ```
  @Component
  public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {


      //Get inputs
      String username = authentication.getName();
      String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();


      //Authenticate against the third-party system (VIA LDAP, WEB SERVICE ,...)
      if (AuthenticateAgainstThirdPartySystem()) {

          //Authentication is OK then create token
          //SecurityContext get updated automatically
          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, new ArrayList<>());

          return authenticationToken;

      } else {
          return null;
      }

  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
      return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
     }
   }
  ```

Also **[This link](https://www.baeldung.com/manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security)** might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried this approach and looks like it is working but it feels so wrong to update security context manually... Let us wait for more people to look at this. If no better solution is available I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I think when you're using custom provider (manually) it means you must update security context by yourself in the provider.

Comment: This partially makes sense. But it seems that `AuthenticationManager` has enough information to do this yourself based on the `Authentication` object returned from custom `AuthenticationProvider`. Though I may have wrong understanding of how all this works. Seems time for me to read spring documentation one more time :D

Comment: Edited, when the process of CustomAuthenticationProvider is done and UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is generated, the SecurityContex get updated automatically, So there is no need to update SecurityContext manually in this level

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation with GraphQL. I wasn't able to use filter authentication because I had single entry point for all requests.
So authentication happen outside of filter chain.

It is correct that if you don't use filter (that extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter) for authenticating user you basically fall out of the chain, and as a result no http session, no security context with authentication you passed.

But the interesting part is that http session and context creation performed not in the heart of spring, but in regular filter. In AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.

If you check AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter then you'll see the mechanic. And you can replicate the same logic in your controller with http session, remember me, security context etc.

This information would help me to save a week of research. May be it will be useful for somebody else.